# Keep switch checked in Android application

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-switch

I have a switch in my Android app. I want to keep that checked until I off it (even I back pressed or open another application). Below is the code that I have tried.

```
mWorkingSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.workingSwitch);
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("com.bitproject.driverapplication", MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean switchState = prefs.getBoolean("service_status", false);
mWorkingSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
      @Override
      public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
         if (isChecked) {
             connectDriver();
         } else {
             disconnectDriver();
         }
     }
});
mWorkingSwitch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("com.bitproject.driverapplication", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
         editor.putBoolean("service_status", mWorkingSwitch.isChecked());
         editor.commit();
     }
});
```

When I backpressed (while switch is checked), and again go to that activity (where the switch is in), that switch has become off.

I want to keep it on until I off it.
There are some similar questions but I can't understand how to relate those to my problem. I'm new to Android.

Comment: save the checked state in shared preferences by setting an oncheckChangedlistener ,get it on activity create and set it to checkbox

Comment: I have tried some coding with your advice (the code in the question have edited to the new one) and had done some modifications inside onCreate. Still, my switch becomes off after I toggle between another activity.

Comment: I have added an answer check it

Answer (score 1):

**Save state in shared preferences in `setOnCheckedChangeListener`:**

```
......
......               
if (isChecked) {
connectDriver();

//switch is checked
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("switch", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("state", "checked");
editor.apply();

} else {
disconnectDriver();

//switch is unchecked
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("switch", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("state", "unchecked");
editor.apply();
}
......
......
```

**Now in `onStart()` method of activity:**

```
@Override
protected void onStart(){
super.onStart();

//read the state
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("switch", MODE_PRIVATE); 
String state = pref.getString("state", "default");

if(state.equals("checked")){

//it was checked

mWorkingSwitch.setChecked(true);

}else{

//it was unchecked

mWorkingSwitch.setChecked(false);

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should also restore its state also in the onCreate method after switchState is assigned:

```
mWorkingSwitch.setChecked(switchState);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok here is the fixed code , you should be saving state in on OnCheckedChangeListener and setting state back with `mWorkingSwitch.setChecked(switchState);`

```
mWorkingSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.workingSwitch);
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("com.bitproject.driverapplication", MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean switchState = prefs.getBoolean("service_status", false);
 mWorkingSwitch.setChecked(switchState);
mWorkingSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
      @Override
      public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
         if (isChecked) {
             connectDriver();
         } else {
             disconnectDriver();
         }

 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("com.bitproject.driverapplication", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
         editor.putBoolean("service_status",isChecked);
         editor.commit();
     }
});
```

You should not be setting onClickListener for switch